# Unable to write ldap object - An object class violation occurred

Tags: powershell, ldap, lotus-domino

I'm trying to write a new object via Powershell using S.DS.P module and getting error "Exception calling "SendRequest" with "2" argument(s): "An object class violation occurred.""

Code:-

```
$Object = [PSCustomObject]@{distinguishedName=$null; cn=$null; objectClass=$null; mail=$null; maildomain=$null; mailserver=$null; mailfile=$null; description=$null; messagestorage=$null; encryptincomingmail=$null; availablefordirsync=$null; displayname=$null}

$Object.distinguishedName = "cn=testmailinfromscript,ou=GB,o=ORG"
$Object.objectClass = "{dominoServerMailInDatabase, top}"
$Object.mail = "testmailinfromscript@test.com"
$Object.maildomain = "some-domain"
$Object.mailserver = "CN=SERVER,OU=GB,O=ORG"
$Object.mailfile = "shadow account"
$Object.description = "shadow account"
$Object.messagestorage = "1"
$Object.encryptincomingmail = "0"
$Object.availablefordirsync = "1"
$Object.displayname = "testmailinfromscript/GB/ORG"
$Object.cn = "testmailinfromscript"

Add-LdapObject -LdapConnection $ldap -Object $Object -Verbose
```

Error:-

```
    Exception calling "SendRequest" with "2" argument(s): "An object class violation occurred."
At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\S.DS.P\S.DS.P.psm1:927 char:13
+             $LdapConnection.SendRequest($rqAdd, $Timeout) -as [System ...
+             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : DirectoryOperationException
```

Any help would be appreciated.

`dominoServerMailInDatabase` schema:

```
ObjectClass: dominoServerMailInDatabase

LDAP name:  dominoServerMailInDatabase      Object Class Type:  Structural Object Class
OID:    2.16.840.1.113678.2.2.2.1.25        Superior Object Class:  top
Notes mapping:  Database                    Auxiliary Object Classes:   
Schema: Lotus Domino Directory              Description:    

Mandatory Attribute Types:  
objectClass     

Optional Attribute Types:   
AvailableForDirSync
Comments
description
displayName
dominoAuthor
dominoCertificate
dominoLocalAdmin
dspAutoProcessForwardTo
dspAutoProcessType
dspAutoProcessUserList
EncryptIncomingMail
fullName
LastMod
mail
MailDomain
MailFile
MailServer
MessageStorage
```

Comment: Typo "DdistinguishedName" in your 1st line

Comment: Thanks, different error after syntax corrected

Comment: @Matt__68 Can you show us the schema entry for `dominoServerMailInDatabase`?

Comment: Apologies, this isn't my speciality, could you confirm the command please.

Comment: Are you certain that the user id that you have used to authenticate to the Domino LDAP server has sufficient access (Editor or above, with the Create document permission) to the Domino Directory to perform this operation?

Comment: Yes, have manager with all roles in ACL

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Schema object added to details

Comment: @Matt__68 First thing I'd try is make sure you use the correct _casing_, eg. `$Object.AvailableForDirSync = "1"` instead of `$Object.availablefordirsync = "1"` and so forth

Comment: Same error unfortunately. I think the issue is with the multiple values in the objectClass

Comment: server console shows:-
27/06/2022 16:51:43.88 LDAP> Entry (cn=testmailinfromscript,ou=GB,o=ORG): OC not found in schema

Comment: Please show the "Get-LdapConnection" line you are using to connect.